# FileUpload fail in google chrome but works in other browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, jakarta-ee

FileUpload codes
from /UploadSubmission Servlet at doPost

```
     try{  
        if (isMultipart)
            {
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
                boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
                UnzipUtility utility = new UnzipUtility();
                try{
                    // Parse the request
                    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);            
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                System.out.println(item.getName());
              //continues
    }    
    catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when i run it, its works for internet explorer, firefox
However, when i run it on google chrome: it give me this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ERROR_DEMO.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Here would be the HTML part

```
<form name="UploadSubmission" id="UploadSubmission"
                action="/JavaProject/UploadSubmission" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
<input type="file" name="fileName"
                            accept="application/zip">
    </form>
```

Comment: maybe this one helps:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368?hl=en